# How to pass formula as condition in drools decision table

Tags: java, drools

I am new to Drools. I am trying to add a custom formula as condition in drools decision table.
Can someone let me know how do we do that?
My formula is: abs(column1 - column2) > 200. When I put it under condition I am getting error Unable to analyze expression 'abs(column1- column2)'.
I tried creating function but it gives me error. Error importing rule.
Below is the stack trace and my function.

Function: function double abs_val(double totalDepth, double bitDepth){ return abs(totalDepth-bitDepth);
}

Error:
Message [id=5, kieBase=defaultKieBase, level=ERROR, path=rules/rules1.xlsx, line=15, column=0
text=Rule Compilation error The import rules.Abs_val cannot be resolved]
Message [id=6, kieBase=defaultKieBase, level=ERROR, path=rules/rules1.xlsx, line=6, column=0
text=Rule Compilation error The import rules.Abs_val cannot be resolved]
Message [id=7, kieBase=defaultKieBase, level=ERROR, path=rules/rules1.xlsx, line=-1, column=0
text=Error importing : 'rules.Abs_val.abs_val']

Answer (score 0):

I am able to pass through this error by other way around.
I created another field to my data object and put my calculations in there.
I passed the object with new field to the decision table.